# Do I need to pre-register my foreign car to drive in Milan's Zone B?

Tags: italy, automobiles, milan

Is there any obligatory online registration or some kind of paid front-window sticker needed to enter Milano's Zone B?

There is an online service for car registration but I'm not sure if every car need to be registered:
https://www.comune.milano.it/servizi/area-b-registrati-e-gestisci-i-permessi

As I understood there are cameras which automatically register the car's 
license plate. Do they then check if your license plate number is registered in some database?

Comment: What is the nationality of the car?

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ, the car is registered in Germany.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Area B` traffic enforcement area is based **only** on poluttion/emission levels of the vehicle. There is no subscription/vignette available for this traffic zone, unlike the `Area C` for which the entry can be purchased.

**What you have to do**

In order to enter the zone (which is the largest in Europe) through its ANPR gates, you have to make sure that your vehicle is compliant with `Euro X` emission standards. In particular, LPG and electric vehicles are free to enter, and the X in the `Euro X` standard varies on the fuel type (gasoline vs diesel) and will likely increase in the future, in a restrictive way.

The emission standard is displayed in the vechicle registration card (Zulassungsbescheinigung, [example Euro 4](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Schadstoffschl%C3%BCssel_EURO_4.pdf)).

**What they have to do**

They have to match the license number of the car with the emission levels to issue a traffic ticket. The City Of Milan has online access to vehicle registration data **in Italy only**.

**Foreigners are immune**

This is verified ([source](https://www.ilsole24ore.com/art/area-b-milano-via-25-febbraio-2019-ABaHSPTB))

> **Foreigners (almost) not punishable**
>
> A primary issue is with vehicles with a foreign license number. Cameras can take pictures of them, but the control system cannot determine whether they can drive.

> In fact, their environmental class is unknown to Italian authorities: one must get real-time access to foreign databases where these cars are licensed, which is impossible. The only thing one can do is to rely on traditional spot checks by the police (when they have time and personnel and if on-board documentation is sufficiently clear).

Basically, if you drive a foreign vehicle the city's Metropolitan Police is unable to obtain data in real time and must let you go.

Answer (score 2):

On the [urbanaccessregulations](https://urbanaccessregulations.eu/countries-mainmenu-147/italy-mainmenu-81/milano-lez-area-b) website it states:

> Area B covers most of the territory of the city of Milan, It is a limited traffic area with no access and circulation for the most polluting vehicles in addition to those with a length exceeding 12 meters that transport goods.
>
> ...
>
> The city of Milan will establish a website where the registration can be done soon.

It then goes on to state the vehicles (mainly HGV’s) that can enter after registration.

It does not say you have to register your vehicle.

Comment: Thank you but in the question I mentioned a registartion service on the official Milano website: https://www.comune.milano.it/servizi/area-b-registrati-e-gestisci-i-permessi